# Webpage shows white space to the right on iPad Safari

Tags: html, css, ipad, mobile-safari

This is the demo: http://demo4plazathemes.com/19/ma_orion3/

On iPad (only), the webpage is not all the way to the right. There is a white space.

The issue is only on iPad. Weird.

I tried the Web Inspector, but everything looked just fine.

Any idea?

Comment: It isn't only ipad. It's caused by the email addresses in the fourth footer column extending out of the container at ~768px

Comment: But on other devices don't have a white space....

Comment: I can see it when I resize my browser to just before your footer columns stack. It's nothing to do with the device. It is everything to do with the document width.